# What language/methods to use to listen to removeable drives in Windows?

Tags: windows, events, drive, listen

What language or method would I use to listen to the event when a removeable drive is plugged into the PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess any language that can work with the Windows API should do. Basically, you listen to the windows message WM_DEVICECHANGE. This alone will let you listen to system-wide messages.

For more specific scenarios look at the API function RegisterDeviceNotification(). Needless to day, C/C++ would be straightforward for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Is your program going to be running as a windows service and waiting?
or is putting a startup script on the removable drive an option in this case?

Comment: Windows XP doesn't allow autorun's for removable devices.

Comment: It does. My pendrive has autorun on it and works like a charm (I'm using PortableApps).

Comment: Really? It comes up with an 'autorun' dialog which allows you to select the action, but doesn't actually have any automatic file executions

Answer (score 0):

This [article on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shchangenotifyregister.aspx) is in C++, and has a solution using the shell change notify register function.