# C# getdrives with type fixed but without usb harddisks?

Tags: c#, usb, hard-drive, getdrivetype

I want to retrieve the list of fixed disks in a system. But C#s GetDrives Fixed Drives are including plug USB Harddisks.

Any idea how I may detect that a fixed Drive is not an USB harddisk or vica versa?

Comment: sorry but internet was down, check the below link...

Answer (score 4):

Solution nicked from [How to get serial number of USB-Stick in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450009/how-to-get-serial-number-of-usb-stick-in-c) :

```
 //import the System.Management namespace at the top in your "using" statement.
 ManagementObjectSearch theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
      "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
```

Comment: Correct, though this will list Sticks and Drives, and a quick look through the properties didn't reveal an easy way to find the Drive letter.

Comment: Apparently ephraim already has those. This solution was intended to show how you'd filter out USB drives. That's why the query was written as `InterfaceType='USB'`, and why it doesn't matter that sticks are included.

Comment: There is no way to match the ManagementObjects and the DriveInfo objects because the query does not return drive letters.

Answer (score 3):

use DriveType to detect the type of the drive:

```
using System.IO;

DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
  if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
  {
    // This is the drive you want...
  }
}
```

[DriveInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx)

EDIT1:

check the following link:
[How do I detected whether a hard drive is connected via USB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220123/how-do-i-detected-whether-a-hard-drive-is-connected-via-usb)

Comment: But DriveType.Removable are just USB Sticks not USB Harddisks.
From Docu: The drive is a removable storage device, such as a floppy disk drive or a USB flash drive.

Comment: USB Harddisks are of Type Fixed exactly that is the Problem!

Comment: It's possible. You can check my solution at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can get list of USB hard disk.

```
//Add Reference System.Management and use namespace at the top of the code.
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject b in queryObj.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject c in b.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk"))
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}" + "\\", c["Name"].ToString())); // here it will print USB drive letter
                }
            }

        }
```

Here you can get list of all fixed drives(System and USB hard disks):

```
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives(); 

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady == true && d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);   
            }           
        }
```

If you compare them,then you can retrieve the list of fixed disks in a system but without USB hard disks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this MSDN link for individual solutions (including finding drive letters):
[WMI Tasks: Disks and File Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)