# how to check if empty flash card reader is present in usb slot?

Tags: c++, winapi

I use `GetLogicalDrives()` to get all drives on my computer but that function shows not only present ready to use volumes but also empty flash-readers with no card in them. Next the `GetDriveType()` shows code 2 for such volume. And that is no matter if the flash card is present or not in the slot. Some multi-readers produce many such non-existing drives, the question is how can I determine the correct status of such volume.

Trying to call `FindFirstFile()` on such non-present drive produces visual error even in console app : `Exception Processing Message c0000013 Parameters 75b3bf7c 4 75b3bf7c 75b3bf7c` After such error the code continues to run, but this annoying error shows up to the user in a window as the app would made a major crash.

So one method of dealing with that would be using FindFirstFile but I do not know any way to get that error out of the way of the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found it! The key to success here is `GetVolumeInformation()`.

It returns 0 and sets last error to 21 when there is an empty card reader in usb slot. :)

Comment: It's probably negligible nowadays for most people, but there is one drawback worth mentioning: Calling `GetVolumeInformation` will make floppy drives produce some noise no matter if a disk is inserted or not. Maybe the more advanced storage APIs could be used to first filter out floppy drives...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few excellent choices:

- [How do I detected whether a hard drive is connected via USB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220123/how-do-i-detected-whether-a-hard-drive-is-connected-via-usb)

In particular:

`if( 2 == ::getDriveType( <driveletter> ))`

Return values of function:

DRIVE_UNKNOWN 0: The drive type cannot be determined.

DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR 1: The root path is invalid; for example, there is no volume mounted at the specified path.

DRIVE_REMOVABLE 2: The drive has removable media; for example, a floppy drive, thumb drive, or flash card reader.

DRIVE_FIXED 3: The drive has fixed media; for example, a hard disk drive or flash drive.

DRIVE_REMOTE 4: The drive is a remote (network) drive.

DRIVE_CDROM 5: The drive is a CD-ROM drive.

DRIVE_RAMDISK 6: The drive is a RAM disk.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wait wait, I *know* that the drive is USB that is type 2, but that may be a pen-drive or usb reader with a flash card or not, and all I want to know is that the card is present or this is only a reader-dummy drive placeholder.